# Increase the speed of a node as time progresses

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Basically I am creating this game and there is a node (ball) that goes around a path at a set speed. That set speed is defined in the GameProcessSettings.h file and the code is as follows,

```
#define SPEED_MOVE_PLAYER_MIN 28
#define SPEED_MOVE_PLAYER_MAX 9000
```

Now in the file that controls the speed of the node, here is the code.

```
- (void)moveTo:(NSString *)moveDirection currentPlayerPosition:(NSString *)playerPosition {
    [self removeAllActions];

    speed-= IncreaseSpeedValue;
    if (speed < SPEED_MOVE_PLAYER_MIN) speed = SPEED_MOVE_PLAYER_MIN;
    else {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }

    SKAction *move;
    if ([moveDirection isEqualToString:@"up"]) move = [SKAction moveToY:self.position.y + PLAYER_MOVE_BY_POINTS duration:speed];
    else if ([moveDirection isEqualToString:@"down"]) move = [SKAction moveToY:self.position.y - PLAYER_MOVE_BY_POINTS duration:speed];
    else if ([moveDirection isEqualToString:@"left"]) move = [SKAction moveToX:self.position.x - PLAYER_MOVE_BY_POINTS duration:speed];
    else move = [SKAction moveToX:self.position.x + PLAYER_MOVE_BY_POINTS duration:speed];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(increaseSpeed) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    IncreaseSpeedValue = -200;

    [self runAction:move];

    _currentMoveDirection = moveDirection;
    _currentPlayerPosition = playerPosition;
}

@end
```

How and what do I use to make the node move faster every second?